# How to get UTC universal time from CLLocation locations?

Tags: ios, nsdate, core-location, cllocationmanager, utc

It looks like the `timestamp` property of `CLLocation` takes the device's current date and time... I have this code snippet:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
   NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;

   long long locTimestamp = [date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
   NSLog(@"Loc timestamp: %lld:", locTimestamp);
}
```

At the moment I'm writing this, if I print the description of `eventDate` in the Xcode's debug area console, I get:

> Printing description of eventDate:
>   2015-08-26 15:14:09 +0000

And if I change the date in the device's settings, I get that wrong date in `evenDate`:

> Printing description of eventDate:
>   2015-07-25 15:16:33 +0000

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the `NSDate` that is returned in the `timestamp` property... it really takes the date and time you have set in the device, or it is just given the format of those device's settings?

The point is, I need to get UTC times of locations to report them to a server and make some comparisons between different devices, and if user changes the date and time settings of his device and my app sends wrong or "fake" timestamps, my app couldn't perform well...

It seems that it is possible in Android apps to get the NMEA data from GPS and then get the universal time of positions, but I can´t find that in iOS. Is it possible to get it in iOS?

I need help with this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Still no answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timestamps into any calendar or timezone you want via the `NSCalendar` and `NSDateFormatter` and `NSLocale`classes. [Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Comment: Thanks. That would get the UTC equivalent of the `NSDate` or timestamp I have... the point is, I need the "real" UTC time, not the UTC equivalent to the time I'm given in a `CLLocation` object, that seems to be taken from the device and not from the GPS data... isn't it?

Comment: These ate the only tools available and unfortunately they are subject to the system time that can be manipulated by the user.